# connecting 2 columns in R isnot working

Tags: r

I try to read data from a file which holds date and time and wrote the following code to concatenate the coulms Date and Time into 1 colum named Datetime:

```
df <-read.csv("file", header=TRUE)
df = data.frame(DateTime=as.POSIXct(paste(df$Date, df$Time)), df)
```

The problem is that the output holds only the Date and not the Time.
I also tried to change the format of the data with `df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date , "%y/%m/%d")` but the output is NA.

Please advice.

The file sample is here:

```
 Date,Time 
 2011/12/22,02:00:00
 2011/12/22,02:01:00
 2011/12/22,02:02:00
 2011/12/22,02:03:00
 2011/12/22,02:04:00
 2011/12/22,02:05:00
 2011/12/22,02:06:00
 2011/12/22,02:07:00
 2011/12/22,02:08:00
 2011/12/22,02:09:00
 2011/12/22,02:10:00
 2011/12/22,02:11:00
 2011/12/22,02:12:00
 2011/12/22,02:13:00
 2011/12/22,02:14:00
 2011/12/22,02:15:00
 2011/12/22,02:16:00
 2011/12/22,02:17:00
 2011/12/22,02:18:00
 2011/12/22,02:19:00
 2011/12/22,02:20:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 df$datetime <- as.POSIXct(paste(df$Date, df$Time), format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S") 
 df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, "%Y/%m/%d")
 head(df,3)
 # (      Date     Time            datetime
 #1 2011-12-22 02:00:00 2011-12-22 02:00:00
 #2 2011-12-22 02:01:00 2011-12-22 02:01:00
 #3 2011-12-22 02:02:00 2011-12-22 02:02:00

 str(df)
 #'data.frame': 21 obs. of  3 variables:
 #$ Date    : Date, format: "2011-12-22" "2011-12-22" ...
 #$ Time    : chr  "02:00:00" "02:01:00" "02:02:00" "02:03:00" ...
 #$ datetime: POSIXct, format: "2011-12-22 02:00:00" "2011-12-22 02:01:00" ...
```